# Deploying cloudflare worker with prisma

Tags: webpack, prisma, cloudflare-workers

I'm following the tutorial for deploying a cloudflare worker with prisma
https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-cloudflare-workers#10-develop-the-cloudflare-worker-function

However in the end when they do
`npx wrangler dev` and everything is supposed to be working I get a bunch of errors

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'
etc
```

I understand it happens due to webpack target `webworker`, but what should I do with it? Tried to mark them as external and couple of other things to ignore errors, but it does look like these things are actually required by the prisma client.

What's the proper way to polyfill dependencies or deal with these errors?

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible to use Prisma in a Cloudflare worker as it needs access to unsupported Node.js APIs as well as npm modules with native extensions. Workers have access to APIs that are listed here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/ Maybe Prisma packaged as a Webassembly module would work, but I can't tell for sure.